# React Native - FETCH Response is empty - API Status 500 - POST Call

Tags: react-native, express

```
    signIn = () => { 
    //post data to express backend
    fetch('http://10.0.2.2:3000/api/v1/auth', {
        method: 'POST',
            header: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },

        body: `login=${this.state.login}&password=${this.state.password}`
    })

    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then ((res => {

        if(res.status === 200) {
           AsyncStorage.setItem('user', this.state.login);
           this.props.navigation.navigate('Authorized')
        } else {
            alert("Response:", res);
        }
    }))
    .done();
}
```

The above is for React-Native. And below is the express backend:

```
    router.post('/', function(req,res){
    var login= req.body.login;
    var password = req.body.password;
    var sql = `SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '${login}' OR number = '${login}' AND password = ${password}`
    db.query(sql, function (err, rows, fields) {
        if (err) {
            res.status(500).send({error: 'Something went wrong!'})
        } else {
            if(rows.length > 0) {
                if (rows[0].password == password) {
                    res.status(200).send({success: 'Login Successful'})
                }
            }  else {
            res.status(404).send({error: 'Email or Password does not match!'})
        }
        }
    })
});
```

I think there is nothing getting into a response or maybe some other problem which I am unable to figure out the moment.

Comment: you will get empty login and password in back-end because your **Content-Type** is not correct edit it to **Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded**

Comment: @Hisham **Thank you so much**, it worked.